# List value not showing on visualforce page in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I Want to show the description of the opportunity on a popup window 
Description show on the debug log. but not showing in the vf page.
I am try a lot but not success.

Here is my code.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="opportunityPageReport" id="pg">
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <style>
                .popup {    
                        display:none;
                        background-color: white;
                        border-width: 1px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        z-index: 9999;
                        left: 50%;
                        padding:10px;
                        position: absolute;
                        height: 160px;
                        width: 450px;
                        margin-left: -250px;
                        margin-top: 15px;
                        top:80px;
                        overflow: auto;
                      }

               .divclose {
                        margin-bottom: 5px; 
                        padding-left: 432px;
                        position:fixed
                        }       
        </style>

        <apex:pageBlock >

            {!oppdislst}

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opplst}" var="opp"  id="TableSort" styleclass="tablesorter" style="width:100%">        
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Amount}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.LeadSource}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.StageName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Type }"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.CloseDate}"/>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!Showdiscription}" id="dis" rerender="popup" onclick="showDiscription()">
                       <apex:param name="discriptionid" value="{!opp.id}"/>
                       <apex:outputText style="color:dodgerblue;text-decoration:none" id="discription"  value="{!if(!(opp.Description != null),"","Description")}"/> 
                    </apex:commandLink>    
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <div id="dis" Class="popup"> 
                <div Class="divclose">
                   <apex:commandLink value="X"  reRender="dis" onclick="hideDiscription()"/>
                </div> 

                {!oppdislst}

                <apex:repeat value="{!oppdislst}" var="dis1">
                    <apex:outputtext value="{!dis1.Description}" />
                </apex:repeat>
            </div>

        </apex:pageBlock>


        <script>       
            function showDiscription(){
                document.getElementById("dis").style.display = "block";
            } 

            function hideDiscription(){
                alert('hello close');
                document.getElementById("dis").style.display = "none";
            } 
        </script>

    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Class**

```
public class opportunityPageReport
{
    public list<opportunity> oppLst {get ; set; }
    public list<opportunity> oppdislst {get; set; }

    public opportunityPageReport()
    {
        system.debug('<<<<<<<<<'+oppdislst);
        oppdislst = new list<opportunity>();
        oppLst = new list<opportunity>();
        list<opportunity> oppTemLst = [SELECT Amount, Name, closeDate, LeadSource, StageName, Type , Description FROM Opportunity ];   

        for(opportunity opp : oppTemlst)
        {
            if(opp.description !=null)
            {
               oppLst.add(opp);
            }
        }
    }

    public pageReference Showdiscription()
    {
        oppdislst = [ select id , Description from opportunity where id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('discriptionid')];
        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+oppdislst);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Pls Help me to find the error in my code.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rerender` works only with [Visualforce components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref.htm) but not with HTML elements like div's.

In command link, change rerender to `popup-body` for instance:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!Showdiscription}" 
    id="dis" rerender="popup-body" onclick="showDiscription()">
```

---

And in put the data to be refreshed in an [outputPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm) with Id as `popup-body`:

```
<div id="dis" Class="popup"> 
    <div Class="divclose">
       <apex:commandLink value="X"  reRender="dis" onclick="hideDiscription()"/>
    </div> 

    <apex:outputPanel id="popup-body">
        {!oppdislst}

        <apex:repeat value="{!oppdislst}" var="dis1">
            <apex:outputtext value="{!dis1.Description}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</div>
```